# Performing a pandas operation on only a subset of columns when a specific criterion in one column is met

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data table with a fairly large amount of columns - around 60. For a subset of around 10 of the columns, I'd like to perform a simple addition of a single value when the value in the date column is a specific date.

I've simplified it here - but I'd like to be able to specify the columns in the dataframe I want to adjust in a line of code - i.e.

```
cols=['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']
```

If we simplify this a shortened version, here's my table:

```
Date    A B C D E F 
1/1/23  4 7 2 0 0 2
2/1/23  4 1 2 4 0 5
3/1/23  3 7 3 3 0 2
4/1/23  4 4 2 5 2 1
5/1/23  8 9 3 1 2 3
6/1/23  3 1 3 4 0 3
```

I want to add 1 to my array of specific columns i.e.

...when the date = 5/1/23.

Result I'm looking for:

```
Date    A B C D E F 
1/1/23  4 7 2 0 0 2
2/1/23  4 1 2 4 0 5
3/1/23  3 7 3 3 0 2
4/1/23  4 4 2 5 2 1
5/1/23  7 8 3 0 2 2
6/1/23  3 1 3 4 0 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
cols = ["A", "B", "D", "F"]

df.loc[df.Date.eq("5/1/23"), cols] -= 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Date  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1/1/23  4  7  2  0  0  2
1  2/1/23  4  1  2  4  0  5
2  3/1/23  3  7  3  3  0  2
3  4/1/23  4  4  2  5  2  1
4  5/1/23  7  8  3  0  2  2
5  6/1/23  3  1  3  4  0  3
```

Comment: I appear to be getting a syntax error?

calc.loc[calc.Date.eq.("5/1/23"), cols] -= 1
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @RichardDixon Can you please edit your question and put the error traceback there?

Comment: @RichardDixon Yes, edit your question and put the full traceback there (with correct formatting).

Comment: Must be my mistake - when I run it on the above dataframe it works fine - but for some reason in my full code I'm getting a syntax error. Must be operator error somewhere.

Comment: @RichardDixon You have extra dot between `eq` and `(` (not `eq.(`, should be `eq(`)

Comment: Perfect - thanks for your help.